# What would you call a avid music lover who listen to all kind of music which are usually top of the chart?

Tags: phrase-requests

What would you call a person who listens to all kind of music which sounds melodious to his ears and not specific to any genre?

A person who likes rock would be rock music fan. But a person who likes music avidly (usually which are top of the chart ones) but  in variety.

I would say Generic music lover. But that does not feel right and simply is tasteless

Comment: Well, technically "pop" means "popular", so "pop music fan" would seem to fit.  But some people consider "pop music" to be a specific genre.

Comment: A *swinger*...?

Comment: To have an eclectic taste in music would encompass the idea of 'all kinds of music', but not the idea of the music being top of the chart.

Comment: I think this is possibly a single-word request without that tag, which requires a sample sentence. There are dozens if not hundreds  of ways to describe such a person.

Comment: Please read [Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity?cb=1).

Comment: Are you describing a hit-song fan? Many radio stations in the US specialize in 'Top 40s,' which are the top 40 songs currently listed as hits. Used to mean sales, now perhaps streaming.

Answer (score 2):

That person ***appreciates*** good music.

> ***appreciate:***  1. transitive verb   If you appreciate something, for example, a piece of music or good food, you like it because you recognize its good
>   qualities.
>
> e.g. 
>   "Anyone can appreciate our music." ([Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/appreciate))

You could also say that the person has ***eclectic*** taste or even that the person is an ***eclectic*** (using the word as a noun).

> ***eclectic***: (adjective) eclectic 1.deriving ideas, style, or taste from a broad and diverse range of sources. "her musical tastes are
>   eclectic"
>
> ***eclectic***: (noun) 
>   A person who derives ideas, style, or taste from a broad and diverse
>   range of sources. ([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/eclectic))

*Example sentences also from Oxford:*

‘But they are not just reactionary *eclectics*; they think they can twist and recombine architectural history in fresh and original ways that would have been unthinkable before modernism wiped the slate clean.’

‘Douglas is the king of jazz's current crop of *eclectics*: He's the kind of guy who shows up at a Jewish wedding with a tango band and proceeds to play Bjork covers.’

‘The two strongest objections each approach levels at the other is the claim that *eclectics* are undisciplined, and that traditionalists are stagnated.’